# Javascript Exporting , Vue Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes

Is it possible to export this / what do i need to do in order to allow this to work. I've made a calendar using javascript which renders via innerHtml and i want to import this into my vue component. Is this possible? I've tried multiple different ways all resulting in errors.
Any advice on how to achieve this would help alot please been brickwalled for a few hours now

Vue file:

```
<template>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row" >
          <div class ="col-3">
          </div> <!-- Left Column-->
        <div class="col-6">
            <h2 class="display-8" id ='whiteWrite'>Make a Reservation</h2>
                <div id ='renderhere'>space for calender</div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class=col>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div id ='hide'> TODO: Graph </div>
        </div> <!-- Middle Column-->

        <div class = "col-3"> 

        </div> <!-- Right Column-->
      </div>
    </div> <!-- Calender Div-->
    </div>
    

</template>

<script> 

export default {
    name: "Fred"
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Js File:

```
"use strict";



class Cal {
    constructor(d, containerId){
        this._date = d;
        this._container = document.getElementById(containerId)


    }

    //Function for prev cal month
    prev(){
        this._date.setMonth(this._date.getMonth() - 1);
        this.render();
    }

    //Function for next cal month
    next(){
        this._date.setMonth(this._date.getMonth() + 1);
        this.render();
    }

    _buildHeader(){
        //Month
        let month = document.createElement('div')
        month.id = 'month';

        let m = document.createElement("span");
        m.innerHTML = this._date.toLocaleString('default', {
            month: 'long'
        });

        //year
        m.innerHTML += ` ${this._date.getFullYear()}` ;

        //define left button and bind click
        let leftBtn = document.createElement('div');
        leftBtn.id = "leftBtn";
        leftBtn.innerHTML = "<";
        leftBtn.addEventListener("click", event => this.prev());

        //define right button and bind click
        let rightBtn = document.createElement('div');
        rightBtn.id = "rightBtn";
        rightBtn.innerHTML = ">";
        rightBtn.addEventListener("click", event => this.next());

        month.appendChild(leftBtn);
        month.appendChild(m);
        month.appendChild(rightBtn);


        //build sun to sat

        let calendarHeader = document.createElement('div');
        calendarHeader.id = "calendarHeader";
        let days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];

        days.forEach((day) =>{
            let d = document.createElement('div');
            d.innerHTML = day;
            d.className = "header";
            calendarHeader.appendChild(d);
        });


        //Add Month year + buttons to header
        this._container.appendChild(month);

        //Add days to header
        this._container.appendChild(calendarHeader);
    }

    _buildBody(){
        let calendarBody = document.createElement('div');
        calendarBody.id = "calendarBody";

        
        //Calendar Details
        let firstDay = this._dayOfTheFirstDay().getDay();
        for (let i = 0; i < firstDay; i++){
            let d = document.createElement('div');
            d.innerHTML = "";
            d.className = 'day';
            calendarBody.appendChild(d);
        }

        //Calendar Details
        let lastDate = this._dayOfTheLastDay().getDate();
        for (let i = 1; i < lastDate + 1; i++){
            console.log(i)
            let d = document.createElement('div');
            d.innerHTML = i;
            d.className = 'day';
            d.id = "day" + i;
            calendarBody.appendChild(d);
        }
        console.log(this._container)
        this._container.appendChild(calendarBody);
    }

    _dayOfTheLastDay(){
        return (new Date(this._date.getFullYear(), this._date.getMonth() + 1, 0));
    }

    _dayOfTheFirstDay(){
        return (new Date(this._date.getFullYear(), this._date.getMonth(), 1));
    }
    //call this function everytime we update calender
    render(){
        this._container.innerHTML = '';
        this._buildHeader();
        this._buildBody();
    }


}


//Renders Calender
const containerId = 'renderhere';
let calendarInstance = new Cal(new Date(), containerId);
calendarInstance.render()
```

Comment: What did you try and what did not work? If it's your own code, consider rewriting it to Vue, this will make it easier to use. The code wasn't written to be used with frameworks and will cause memory leaks.

Comment: Fixed the issue, ported the component into my main.js file and loaded it that way

Comment: If you resolved it yourself, consider adding a answer yourself with the working code and marking it as answer. It might help others who are facing similar issue